# Watershed tool producing same output as basin tool for all pour points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, arc-hydro, hydrology-toolset

I am using the Hydrology Tools in the Spatial Analyst Toolbox (ArcGIS 10.3)

I am trying to delineate watersheds in a region in order to do spatial interpolation by top-kriging at some ungaged sites.  I have followed all the intermediary  steps for the delineation (Filling, Flow Direction, Flow Accumulation, Pour Point Snapping) successfully. However, when I get to the Watershed tool, regardless of where I place the pour points, the output I get is the basin (generated with the Basin tool) in which the pour point is located. For example in the image attached, the output from the basin tool is shown on the left. When I run the watershed tool with the snapped pour point in red, the delineated watershed (in green, on the right) is just the basin in which the pour point is located instead of the upstream contributing catchment for that particular pour point.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You have tagged this as arc-hydro. I suggest you update your question with which version you are using, version of ArcGIS, any service packs and license level.

Comment: I'd recommend using the [ArcHydro Toolset](http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/) instead of the Spatial analyst version. Gives you more control and has a lot more features for exactly this kind of analysis.

Comment: I switch to using the ArcHydro Toolset as suggested and it worked just fine. Thanks for the suggestion.